# terminal script for renaming folders in a specific scheme

Tags: command-line

i have about hundreds of movie files stored each in a folder. the scheme i named each folder is like this:

**ABCD**

for movies with titles starting with A,B,C or D for example. In this folder are those movie folders like this

**Blade Runner 2049 (2017) 0526 20180223Eph**

0526 is a specific number for this file/folder.

I'd like to rename all folders to this scheme:

**(0526) Blade Runner 2049 (2017) 20180223Eph**

but i don't know how to do this on my mac?! please note, that some folders don't have the suffix like **20180223Eph**.

It should be done for all movies in one turn - renaming all by using finder would be a little to long...

Thanks in advance,

mnasdaq

[image: sorting of my movies]

Comment: Is the "specific number" always 4 digits?

Comment: yes - from 0001 to - potentially 9999.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I have to say that the *example* `bash` *code* used in this answer, shown further below, is by no means robust, **however it does get the job done!**

With the following as a representative sample of the *hierarchical structure of directories*:

```
.
├── ABCD
├── EFGH
├── IJKL
├── MNOP
│   ├── A Most Violent Year (2014) 1180 20150807Lov
│   ├── A Most Wanted Man (2014) 1146
│   ├── A Nightmare on Elm Street (2010) 0432
│   ├── A Perfect Getaway (2009) 0433
│   └── ¡NO! (2012) 0939
├── QRST
├── UVWX
└── YZ
```

Then after running the *example* `bash` *code* saved as a `bash` *script*, and run from within the *directory* containing the *hierarchical structure* show above, the results for the *directories* will be as shown below, and being as the stated desired output based on the representative sample of the *hierarchical structure of directories* shown above:

```
.
├── ABCD
├── EFGH
├── IJKL
├── MNOP
│   ├── (0432) A Nightmare on Elm Street (2010)
│   ├── (0433) A Perfect Geatway (2009)
│   ├── (0939) ¡NO! (2012)
│   ├── (1146) A Most Wanted Man (2014)
│   └── (1180) A Most Violent Year (2014) 20150807Lov
├── QRST
├── UVWX
└── YZ
```

To use the *example* `bash` *code*, In **Terminal** `cd` to the *directory* containing the `ABCD`, `EFGH`, etc. *directories* and run the following *commands*:

```
touch rendir; nano rendir
```

In `nano` copy and paste the *example* `bash` *code*, show below, into the `rendir` file and then press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and then <kbd>Y</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Next:

```
chmod u+x rendir
```

Now that it's executable, run it by typing:

```
./rendir
```

Then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to run it.

***Example* `bash` *code*:**

```bash
#!/bin/bash

find -E . -type d -regex '.* [0-9]{4}$' > /tmp/foo

while read -r l; do
    p="$(dirname "$l")"
    d="$(basename "$l")"
    n="$(awk '{print "("$NF")"}'<<<"$d")"
    f="$(awk '{$NF=""; sub(/ $/, "", $0); print $0}'<<<"$d")"
    echo mv "$l" "$p/$n $f"
done</tmp/foo

find -E . -type d -regex '.* [0-9]{4} .*$' > /tmp/foo

while read -r l; do
    p="$(dirname "$l")"
    d="$(basename "$l")"
    n="$(awk '{print "("$(NF - 1)")"}'<<<"$d")"
    f="$(awk '{$(NF - 1)=""; print $0}'<<<"$d" | awk 'sub(/  /," ")')"
    echo mv "$l" "$p/$n $f"
done</tmp/foo

rm /tmp/foo
```

Note that as coded, it will output the `mv` *commands* that would be executed if `echo` wasn't there. After testing and examining the output to see that the `mv` *commands* are properly formed, you can the edit `rendir` (`nano rendir`) and remove the two occurrences of `echo`, saving the file, again using (<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and then <kbd>Y</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>) and executing it again.

At this point you should have the desired output as shown in the second `tree` *hierarchical structure of directories* shown above. This *example* `bash` *code* does not account for any deviation from what was expressed in the OP and comments to the OP.

---

**NOTE: You should never run *code* without first being properly backed up and or testing the *code* on a sample copy of the originals.**

---

If I knew `awk` better I'd imagine that an `awk` *program* could be written to manipulate the *input string* to the desired *output string* in a single calling of `awk`, but I don't know `awk` well enough to achieve that.

**Note:** The *example* `bash` *code* is just that and does not employ any *error handling* and is meant only to show one of many ways accomplish a task. The onus is always upon the User to add/use appropriate *error handling* as needed/wanted.